# cart empty after payment fail issue in magento 1.9.3

Tags: cart, onepage-checkout, magento1.9.3

How can I stop Magento to empty cart after the customer fails to pay with a card?
**I am using Midtrans: Veritrans-Payment module for payment method.**

I am using Magento ver.1.9.3

Please give me a quick solution

Comment: This depends on which payment module are you using for card payments... as the responsible code will probably be there

Comment: What payment method you are using?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I am using Midtrans: Veritrans-Payment module

Comment: Share the link.

Comment: @SukumarGorai https://github.com/veritrans/SNAP-Magento

Comment: I have also found one extension https://github.com/veritrans/vtdirect-magento Are you sure you are using the extension you have shared?

Comment: @SukumarGorai  I am using  https://docs.midtrans.com/en/snap/integration_magento.html

I think both are same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87947/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-meera).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default failure action of magento 1 as your payment module didn't override it. If you check the below file:

> /app/code/community/Midtrans/Snap/controllers/PaymentController.php

Locate the method or action **responseAction()** you can see that the code redirect user to default failure page of magento 1. So you need to override the default failure action which looks like below:

```
public function failureAction()
{
    $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

    if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Replace the above code by overriding failure action with below code:

```
public function failureAction()
{
    $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

    if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()){
        if ($lastQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId()){
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($lastQuoteId);
            $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module_name')->__('Inform the customer for failed transaction'));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); //Redirect to cart
        return;
    }

    if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Also comment the below line from your **reponseAction()**:

```
$this->cancelAction();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, this code is not working for me.

Comment: Does your page redirect to failure action? Try to add log and check if it redirects to correct action or not